# Group By in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working in a web page where customers make orders. A customer can have many orders meaning that when I list the orders some customers appear twice. I am grouping the customers by the Due Date and I got that. The problem is that when I pass the json to the front end, the values do not show. I guess that the problem is because in my get method I am not passing my objects types and in my front end I need them but I do not know how to pass them.

This is how my [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKFIu.png) looks. As you can see, I got John two times because he has 2 orders.

This is what I have been trying in ASP.NET Core in my `Get` method:

```
[Route("~/api/order")]
public IQueryable<Order> GetRegistrationSummaryAll()
{
    var newList = _database.Orders
        .Include(q => q.Client)
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.DueDate })
        .Select(y => new Order
        {
            Id = y.Max(x => x.Id),
            ClientId = y.Max(x => x.ClientId),
            InventoryId = y.Max(x => x.InventoryId),
            Quantity = y.Max(x => x.Quantity),
            Price = y.Max(x => x.Price),
            LogoId = y.Max(x => x.LogoId),
            DueDate = y.Key.DueDate
        }
        );
    return newList;
}
```

My model is this one:

```
public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int InventoryId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int LogoId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
        public Logo Logo { get; set; }
        public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the Json result I got from my get method group by. If you see my object type client, inventory and logo are null because I am sending nothing in my get method:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "clientId": 1,
    "inventoryId": 1,
    "quantity": 5,
    "price": 100.0,
    "logoId": 1,
    "dueDate": "2021-09-13T00:00:00",
    "client": null,
    "inventory": null,
    "logo": null,
    "events": null
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "clientId": 2,
    "inventoryId": 3,
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 200.0,
    "logoId": 2,
    "dueDate": "2021-09-15T00:00:00",
    "client": null,
    "inventory": null,
    "logo": null,
    "events": null
  }
]
```

Comment: Please share the JSON being served up (dev tools in Chrome, Network tab).

Comment: Hey, what is your question exactly? It would be easier to help :)

Comment: @Morasiu The question will be how I can declare an object type in my select?

Comment: @mjwills I post the Json now

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't group data or read anything from databases. It's a web app framework. Are you using an ORM like EF Core? Which version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should include more data in your `select`. Or maybe change it so you don't have to think about it like that:

```cs
var newList = someDataFromDatabase
            .GroupBy(x => x.DueDate)
            .SelectMany(a =>
                        a.OrderByDescending(b => b.Id) // HERE YOU CAN PUT SOME MAX 
                        .OrderByDescending(b => b.Price)
                       )
            .First();
```

You can see the full example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EBdR1P)